# c++ ShellExecute not working

Tags: windows, windows-7, shellexecute

I am working on a c++ program that is supposed to launch internet explorer and display a local html file on Windows 7. I am trying to use ShellExecute, but it doesn't work. I googled around, but could not find an answer that worked. Here is the code:


`ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "start iexplore %userprofile%\\Desktop\\html_files\\file.hml", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);`



I copied the command into a system() call just to see if it would work, and it did. Here is the system() call I tried:

```
system("start iexplore %userprofile%\\Desktop\\html_files\\file.html");
```

Since the system call worked, its clearly a problem with ShellExecute. Basically, Internet Explorer does not come up. Everything compiles correctly, though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think IE will recognize environment variables in URI's. In fact `%` have special meaning.

Something like this should work:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
     ShellExecute(NULL, "open",
                  "C:\\progra~1\\intern~1\\iexplore.exe",
                  "file:///C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/html_files/file.html",
                  "",
                  SW_MAXIMIZE); 
     return 0;
}
```

Another way, obtain the %userprofile% enviroment variable value and concat your URI:

```
#if (_MSC_VER >= 1400) 
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)    // Disabling deprecation... bad...
#endif 

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
     std::string uri = std::string("file:///") + getenv("USERPROFILE") + "/Desktop/html_files/file.txt";

     ShellExecute(NULL, "open",
                  "C:\\progra~1\\intern~1\\iexplore.exe",
                  uri.c_str(),
                  "",
                  SW_MAXIMIZE); 

     return 0;
}
```

Im disabling warnings here, but you should use `_dupenv_s` instead of `getenv`.

Good luck.

Comment: You are correct; ie doesn't work with %- I just tested it. Do you know of any alternatives to %userprofile% ?

Comment: Well, you could use: `getenv ("USERPROFILE");` to get the value of the enviroment variable and save that into a string. Then  call `ShellExecute`.

Comment: Use [`ExpandEnvironmentStrings()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724265(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The paths of the user's shell folders, including the Desktop, can be customized by the user, so `%userprofile\desktop` is not guaranteed to be the correct path on all systems.  The *correct* way to get the user's *actual* Desktop path is to use [`SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Desktop)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx).

You do not need to know the path to iexplorer.exe, Windows known how to find it. So just specify "iexplorer.exe" by itself as the `lpFile` parameter and the HTML filename as the `lpParameter` parameter:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "iexplore.exe", "full path to\\file.hml", NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

With that said, this is very IE-specific. If you want to load the file in the user's default HTML browser/viewer, set the `lpVerb` parameter to NULL and the HTML file as the `lpFile` parameter:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, "full path to\\file.hml", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

This is the same as if the user had double-clicked on the file in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Yeah, this is much better.